# Appending a string to the end of a URL in a variable in PHP

Tags: php, url, append

So I have this code for a youtube link in a wordpress widget

```
 $title  = "<h5 class='widget_title sidebar_widget_title'><a
 href='http://www.youtube.com/user/".$options['username']."'
 target='_blank'>".$options['title']."</a></h5>";
```

So I'm trying to append

> ?sub_confirmation=1

after my youtube user name so that a subscribe confirmation comes up but wow I have tried everything and am just not a good enough coder yet.

Comment: It works the same way as you already concatenate the string. And show what you've tried then you get better feedback because it's more clear where you hit the roadblock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just insert the query string parameter to the string.

```
$title  = "<h5 class='widget_title sidebar_widget_title'><a href='http://www.youtube.com/user/".$options['username']."?sub_confirmation=1' target='_blank'>".$options['title']."</a></h5>";
```

The reason this is possibly confusing to you is because the author of the code you're changing used `"` to tell PHP that the next sequence of characters form a string, and `'` to tell HTML that this is the value for the href attribute (like `<a href='youtube.com'>...</a>`). This works because HTML supports both `"` and `'`, and it saves you the hassle of having to escape quotes.

Personally, I'd rather use `'` for PHP-strings and regular `"` for HTML, but that's a matter of taste.